# Articles with colors

Tags: articles

[Here's](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dingy) an example half-sentence from Collins

> ...wallpaper with stripes of dingy yellow.

[Here's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/dingy) an example sentence from Cambridge

> Her hair was **a** dingy brown colour.

Why do they use an article in the second instance but not in the former?

Answer (score 4):

This question is about how to follow the rules of countability with colour words.

The word "colour" here is a countable noun, so we have to use "a".

With actual colour words like "yellow", "red", etc., things are a bit different. They can be treated as countable or uncountable, with slightly different meanings.

If you treat a colour as uncountable, as in your first example, it refers to the *range of colours* included in the word as a mass noun, rather than one specific tone.

Colour words can also be used in a countable way. This refers to one specific tone of the colour, not the entire range:

> ...wallpaper with stripes of **a** dingy yellow

So in this example, the stripes are of a specific variety of yellow, which happens to be dingy.

Comment: My UK mother, a gifted dressmaker, with a background in retail drapery, used to say of things, e.g.: 'I wonder if they have it in **a** green?'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think that's still common and not limited to colors. For example: "I need that shirt in a large, but the store only has small." (The use of an article for the first size but not the second suggests that there are some subtleties here.)

Comment: But the Collins example goes without the article

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Does my answer not explain why?

Comment: I don't think so. You said if it's a specific yellow, it should go with the article. Both examples, including the one with no article, mention a specific yellow

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev "Dingy yellow" refers to a range of colours. "A dingy yellow" refers to one specific colour within the range of dingy yellow colours.

Comment: Shouldn't we use "the" when it's something specific?